# problems with fedora and libtinfo.so.6

Tags: c++, linux, fedora, ncurses

I am currently on F37 and I get the following problem when I try to run a program that uses `ncurses`; I wrote the program myself, but I was able to get it working on other distros.

```bash
./others: /lib64/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by ./others)
./others: /lib64/libncurses.so.6: no version information available (required by ./others)
```

If I go in the directory `/lib64` or `/usr/lib64`, I am able to find these files. I don't know why it has this problem.

**Disclaimer**: I have already installed everything related to `ncurses`, but I had no luck

I tried to search on the internet but I wasn't able to get any solution.

Since it wasn't clear, I already have recompiled it on Fedora and that's when it stopped working (I have tried to compile the same code on raspberry pi and on WSL and it doesn't bother me with anything related to this problem)

Comment: linux binaries aren't generally portable, you should build the binary on the target distribution. Building on the oldest distribution you want to support can work too

Comment: You've *almost* done everything correctly.  The "gotcha" was assuming your app was *binary* portable across different distros.  Your executable *might* work...or it might fail.  Depending on the distro.  On the other hand, since you're using [ncurses](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1124), your app is very likely *source portable*.  Between *Linux distros*, and probably most different *platforms* (e.g. MacOS and Windows).  All you have to do is *rebuild* from source on the target platform.

Comment: I have already recompiled it, I just forgot to write it down because it seemed obvious to me that I had to compile it for the specifici platform